# Dart declare multiple variables on one line

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to declare multiple variables on one line in Dart. I tried:

`var a = 1, var b = 2;`

but my IDE said it expected a `;` where the comma was so I guess that's a no go. Of course if I *do* use a semi colon like this:

`var a = 1; var b = 2;`

My IDE will format them like this instead:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
```

How can I make them all on one line?

Comment: you mean: `var a = 1, b = 2;`?

Comment: Remove var from b like var a = 1, b = 2; it will work.

Comment: What about if they are different data types? Doesn't seem to work for `int coke = 7, double jim = 4;`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = {}, d = [];
```

Comment: how to do it if for example if also  b = 1, c = 1, ... ?